# Is there a linear transformation who domain isn't all of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

My prof said that for a linear transformation:

$$T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$$

for some real $n$ and $m$, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called the domain.

But some "normal" functions have domains that have restrictions. (i.e. $f(x) = \sqrt(x)$ has restrictions on its domain that $x\ge 0$). Are there any linear transformations that have restrictions on their domain?

Comment: No. Linear (in fact all functions) functions are defined on all of their domain. If one writes $f\colon A\to B$ then $A$ is always the domain. Thus the square root function better be written as $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: I don't think there are any restrictions on the domain of a linear transformation. Linear transformations are maps from vector space to vector space, and for vector space we can usually think of them as $\mathbb{R}^n$. The reason we like linear transformations is that they are really nice maps, i.e. linear. You can think about linear functions like $f(x) = ax + b$, will you have restrictions on that function?

Answer (score 1):

As a practical matter, no. One is always free to consider the restriction of a function (like a linear transformation) to a smaller domain, but the *natural* domain of a function (as defined by some expression or formula) is taken to be the largest domain where the formula makes sense. In the case of a linear transformation $T$ defined by the formula $T(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j} x_j, \ldots, \sum_{j=1}^n a_{mj}x_j)$, the natural domain would be the entire vector space $\mathbb{R}^n = \{(x_1, \ldots, x_n): x_i \in \mathbb{R}\}$ (if we are in the context of real vector spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Let $V, W$ be linear spaces and $T : V \to W$ a linear map.  Then for any subspace $ U \subset V$, the restriction of the map $T$ to the subspace $U$, denoted $T_U$ is another linear map $U \to W$.