# Why do all linear transformations have no restrictions on their natural domains?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Some normal functions have restrictions on their natural domains, but linear functions don't. Why?

Related: [Is there a linear transformation who domain isn't all of $\mathbb{R}^n$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525178/is-there-a-linear-transformation-who-domain-isnt-all-of-mathbbrn)

**Why my question is *not* a duplicate of the above question**: The above question asks if there asks if there is *any* function whose domain isn't $\mathbb{R}^n$. This function clearly exists by limiting the domain of any linear transformation. My question is asking about the *natural domain* of a linear transformation, which none of the answers from the question above address.

**Natural Domain:** The largest domain where the transformation makes sense. In other words, the domain of a linear transformation, without any artificial "restrictions" put on it.

Comment: What's a  *natural domain* of a linear transformation?

Comment: @EnjoysMath The largest domain where the transformation makes sense. In other words, the domain of a linear transformation, without any artificial "restrictions" put on it.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: The earlier question asked, "Are there any linear transformations that have restrictions on their domain?" I don't see any significant distinction between that question and yours.

Comment: @GerryMyerson The question never changed! :)

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me. By "the earlier question", I mean the related one, the one you link to. I don't see how your question differs from what I quoted from that earlier question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well, the earlier question has the trivial answer -  Yes, if you set up an artificial restriction (which is what all the answers basically said!). This question can't be answered with that trivial answer, so I feel this question is justified.

Comment: given that $L(aV)=aL(V)$ then "naturally" you can extend any definition to infinity by taking a large $a$.

Comment: @Maesumi Sorry, you've lost me. Could you please explain it more explicitly and with more details?

Comment: If your linear transformation is $L$ and it is defined at the vector $V$ then $L(V)$ is given. Now $L$ is linear if $L(aV)=aL(V)$ by definition of linearity. So then $L$ is defined on the entire line containing $V$. There cannot be any missing piece of this line.

Comment: @AgustíRoig All real numbers, all real numbers except for zero and all real numbers greater than 0. Why doesn't it make sense? Its simply the set of all values that give you a determinate value when plugged into the function!

Comment: So, what are the "restrictions" on their "natural domains" for these functions? -As far as I can see, "natural domain" and "natural domain with restriction" is the same thing. Part of your problem, I guess, is that you think that a function is a "formula" where you "plug" values. But it's not: a function, a map, implies its domain. When you say "I have a map $f: A \longrightarrow B$", you're already saying that this map is defined on all $A$. So, it doesn't make sense to wonder about a linear map $f: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ not defined on the *whole* $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The moment you write: "let's have a map $f: A \longrightarrow B$", you're already saying "$f$ is defined on the whole of $A$". For instance: it doesn't make sense to talk about "the function $1/x : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$". This function is not defined for $0 \in \mathbb{R}$. So its domain is $\mathbb{R} \setminus \left\{ 0\right\}$.

Comment: In other words: the ol' reliable, simple mathematical concept of "domain" already included your "natural domain" or "natural domain with restrictions".

Comment: If you move to infinite dimensions (more precisely to topological vector spaces) then [unbounded linear operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator) are often defined on a strict subspace, and (in the case where they are genuinely not bounded/continuous) *cannot* be naturally extended to the whole space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempt to understand the question.

Imagine that the natural domain of the linear transformation $T$ is some proper subset $A$ of ${\bf R}^n$. By linearity, $T$ extends to the span of $A$, and is linear on that span, so we may assume $A$ is a subspace of ${\bf R}^n$. Now you can define $T$ to be zero on the complement of $A$, and you will have a linear transformation that extends your original to all of ${\bf R}^n$. And that's why there is no restriction on the natural domain of a linear transformation.

EDIT: As Anthony points out in the comments, I got the extension of $T$ wrong. Extend the basis $\{\,v_1,v_2,\dots,v_r\,\}$ of $A$ to a basis $\{\,v_1,v_2,\dots,v_r,v_{r+1},\dots,v_n\,\}$ of ${\bf R}^n$, define $T(v_j)=0$ for $r+1\le j\le n$, and then extend $T$ to all of ${\bf R}^n$ by linearity.

Comment: Thanks Gerry! What's a complement though? Wikipedia's definition is very technical and hard to understand.

Comment: "complement" in the sense of elementary set theory; the complement of a subset $P$ of a set $Q$ is all the stuff in $Q$ that's not in $P$.

Comment: You don't define it as zero on the set-theoretic complement - this would result in a non-linear function. You need a complement in the linear-algebraic sense (a subspace $B$ such that $A + B = \mathbb R^n$ and $A \cap B = \{0\}$). I'd say the easiest way to understand this is completing a basis of $A$ to a basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and defining $T$ to be zero on each of the new basis vectors.

Comment: While the extension of the definition on $A$ to the span of $A$ is unique, and therefore a natural thing to consider, the further extension to the whole space as described in the EDIT part depends heavily on the choice for extending the basis (and more exactly on the choice of a complementary subspace to the span of $A$). Therefore the latter no longer follows the original definition, and I don't think one can really consider the whole space as a _natural_ domain of that original definition, as OP asks.

Answer (score 3):

There are frequent cases where one wants to define a linear function only on a subspace of a vector space. Although any linear map on a subspace can be extended to the whole space, there will in general be many ways to do it, and none of the choices might be better than any others. Also if infinite dimensional spaces are involved the existence of the extension might depend on the axiom of choice.

An archetypical example of the situtation is the follwing. Let $f:V\to W$ be an injective but not surjective linear map, then $f$ induces an isomorphism $\newcommand\im{\operatorname{Im}}\tilde f:V\to\im(f)\subset W$. The inverse isomorphism $\tilde f^{-1}:\operatorname{Im}(f)\to V$ is naturally defined only on $\im(f)$; it could be extended to $W$ but not uniquely so, and the extension would no longer be an isomorphism. For a case where the existence of an extension requires the axiom of choice, take this example with $f$ the inclusion $\Bbb Q\to\Bbb R$ as a linear map of $\Bbb Q$-vector spaces.

For an example of a practical use of such partially defined linear maps, look at the proof of the rank-nullity theorem I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/495275/18880). There $\varphi$ is not injective, but its section (right-inverse) $g$ is defined only on$~\im(\varphi)$, and it should not be extended to $K^m$ for the purpose of the proof.